# How to hide(not remove) any contact from Skype list?

Tags: windows-xp, skype

How to hide(not remove) any contact from Skype list? I just want to hide the user from list don't want to remove contact of that user permanently.

Same like "Never Show" option in gmail. I just want to hide any contacts temporary from in my skype, don't want to inform that user. and i don't want to remove contact permanently

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a work-around (since no other answers have yet been posted): edit the user in question, putting a "Z" or "z" (depending on sort-order issues) in front of their name. Then that user goes to the bottom of the list. Change the size of the window so those users don't show (unless you have too many other users to fit; but at least the ones you don't want are now segregated to the end of the list).

Comment: Definitely a hack, but an interesting hack. +1

Comment: If there is no other way then this is the best way.

Answer (score 4):

You can enable contacts category (Skype menu | Contacts | Contacts categories | See all Contacts Category), create new category, let say "hidden" and move contacts you temporary don't want to see there.

In Skype main window, select "Ungrouped" category to see all contacts except those you put in "hidden" category.

Answer (score 0):

Found a complete solution to it. It's not a workaround.

1) Install the Skype app on your mobile and block it from your mobile phone instead of blocking from your laptop.

2) You'll now see that the contact is no longer in your Skype contact list. It's not removed, but blocked. So you need to worry. To re-enable it back/ to see them once again in your Skype, follow this instruction:

> Skype Options|Privacy|Blocked Contacts| Unblock

Comment: That doesnt sound like a solution, because the user will not be able to contact you anymore, and the whole point of the question was just to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to answer this question. But it may help future users.

In skype, Go to **Contacts >> Contact List >> Create new list**

One can right click on profile names displayed on the left side of skype and add needed contacts to the new list. Then later on top of all profile names there is a small dropdown which shows **all** by default. Instead select the list name from there.

Answer (score -2):

If you know the username or email address by heart you can always delete the contact and add it back when you need it, your contact won't notice as him or her will not receive any further new contact notifications from you.

Comment: The author specifically indicates removal of the contact isn't option