# When I delete a contact from Skype, is this contact informed?

Tags: skype

When I delete a contact from Skype, is this contact informed?

If so, can I delete without informing him?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are deleting a contact from your Skype, it won't inform.

If you are not really interested in deleting permanently, refer this answer **[How to hide(not remove) any contact from Skype list?](https://superuser.com/a/114593/103323)** for some workaround to make user hide.

Comment: Al right, so if I delete a friend from Skype, he won't be informed (and will I be deleted from his contacts list ?)

Comment: @Patrick - He would have to remove you from his list.  You can't remove yourself from another person's friends list.

Comment: So, once I've given the permission to add myself, I can't anymore to be remove myself and my privacy is compromised ?

Comment: @Patrick If you tell someone your phone number, how would you 'un-tell' them?  :)  You can make a piece of private information public once, and there's no take-backs. ;)

Comment: A phone number has not my picture, other informations I'm going to update, etc.. but is not a big problem

Comment: @Patrick AFAIK his skype list will now display you as unknown, he can't see if you are online and your name will appear grey. Depending on how you have your privacy settings he may also be unable to view your status.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete them, they will know, since there will be a question mark on your name.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.com, thanks for the answer. However, please don't add unrelated links or contact information to answers. You can add this information to your profile page.